# Dot Net : Exporting content from gridview to excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi need some help in exporting from gridview to excel file.

The following code I have use actually export the whole web page instead of content from the gridview. I would want to only export content from the gridview itself. Please help, thanks~

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=data.xls";
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            string tab = "";
            foreach (DataColumn dc in gvSessionList.Columns)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
            int i;
            foreach (DataRow dr in gvSessionList.Rows)
            {
                tab = "";
                for (i = 0; i < gvSessionList.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                    tab = "\t";
                }
                Response.Write("\n");
            }
            Response.End();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, however if you had read my question carefully, I have stated my issue clearly.. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a grid view displays information from a data table such as the below code.

```
    GridView.DataSource = DataTableResult;
    GridView.DataBind();
```

One can save the data table in a session variable such as

```
    Session["ExportDataTableResult"] = DataTableResult;
```

Then when the user clicks the Export to Excel button that method can take the stored data table and generate the excel file

```
    if(Session["ExportDataTableResult"] != null)
     {
      ExportToExcel((System.Data.Datatable)Session["ExportDataTableResult"])
     }
```

For the method that takes a data table and write into excel file i believe one can find examples of it in the internet.Hope i have given you a general idea of one way of exporting from gridview to excel file.

Comment: Hi C.Poh, I have noted your advice. Thanks alot. My current issue is I have no idea why the code above I have use export the whole web page instead of my gridview. And I thought my code has pointed to my gridview (gvSessionList). =(